# JPA: How to perform a LIKE with a NUMBER column in a static JPA MetaModel?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, metamodel

I do have a static metamodel with a NUMBER (actually, BigDecimal, don't ask why) column. Now I would like to do a LIKE query against that number column:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb;
cb.like(entity.get(Entity_.numbercol), "123%");
```

where `entity.get(Entity_.numbercol)` returns a `Path<BigDecimal>`. Naturally, I get a compile error: `...like(Expression<String>, ...) ... not applicable for the arguments (Path<BigDecimal>, ...)`

Casting the column with `.as(String.class)` fails due to some Bug in JPA, but I don't have the bug number at hands right now. It is not fixed in the latest version of JPA/Hibernate, though. Anyway, it results in a runtime exception about some invalid SQL statement being generated.

Now I just need a way to get the criteria API equivalent of the SQL

```
... WHERE numbercol LIKE '123%';
```

Searching for the topic already brought up the following responses, which don't help because I have a static metamodel:
[NHibernate - easiest way to do a LIKE search against an integer column with Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231054/nhibernate-easiest-way-to-do-a-like-search-against-an-integer-column-with-crit) and [JPA/Criteria API - Like & equal problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014390/jpa-criteria-api-like-equal-problem)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Comment: As a workaround and because it is ensured that the wildcard is always the last character of the search string/number, I create a bunch of between expressions, e.g. for `123%` I have `=123 OR between (1230,1239) OR between(12300, 12399) OR between(123000, 123999)` and so on. Not the best way but at least it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not fail because of bug, it works as specified (for example in [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29)):

> Perform a typecast upon the expression, returning a new expression
>   object. This method does not cause type conversion: the runtime type
>   is not changed. Warning: may result in a runtime failure.

Method you use performs cast and you need conversion. In general there is no support to convert from BigDecimal to String in JPA.

Comment: Well, I know about that but there is also somewhere a bug which we stepped over. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out here in this context, that should help.

Answer (score 12):

For the people, who are still looking for a solution.

Knowing that HQL`str` function does the job (at least for Hibernate v. 3.6.9.Final) one can  implement his own `FunctionExpression` like:

```
//plagiarized from org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.function.CastFunction
public class StrFunction<Y extends Number> extends BasicFunctionExpression<String> implements FunctionExpression<String>, Serializable {
    public static final String FCT_NAME = "str";

    private final Selection<Y> selection;

    public StrFunction(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Selection<Y> selection) {
        super((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, String.class, FCT_NAME);
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerParameters(ParameterRegistry registry) {
        Helper.possibleParameter(selection, registry);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(CriteriaQueryCompiler.RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        return FCT_NAME + '(' + ((Renderable) selection).render(renderingContext) + ')';
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
cb.like(new StrFunction<Long> (cb, root.get(MyObject_.id)), "%mySearchTerm%");
```