# Wild card search on Long value using Criteriabuilder query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I want to use wild card search on a field which is a Long value (in Entity class) and Integer in database.Here Contact is entity class which has field : Id as Long value in  entity class and as a Integer in database.The following is code.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = builder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Contact> root = query.from(Contact.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (searchCriteria.getContactId() != null) {
    if(searchCriteria.getContactId().contains("%")){                
       predicates.add(builder.like( 

       (root.get(Contact_.id)),-->Note this line

       builder.literal(searchCriteria.getContactId()+"%")));

        }
    }
```

Here builder.like will not accept root.get(Contact_.id)  as  Contact_.id is a long value.We will get compilation error here.Here searchCriteria.getContactId() is string value.

**Is there any way to cast the root.get(Contact_.id) as string type?**

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Contact, Long> id;
```

So far I have tried with

```
((Expression<String>)(root.get(Contact_.id).as(String.class).
```

But i am getting query syntax exception.It is not able to convert it to perfect syntax. It is giving query like -> **( cast(generatedAlias0.id as varchar(255)) but not as ( cast(generatedAlias0.id as string))** when i look at logs.

Comment: Compiler error is expected as `CriteriaBuilder.lower()` method accepts string expressions only. What you actually trying to do is getting lowercase from the long argument.

Comment: @wypieprz Hi,Thank you very much for going into this issue.Is there any way to convert this (root.get(Contact_.id)) to string?

Comment: Why would you need such conversion anyway? Could you please give an example of what you are trying to achieve, i.e. using JPQL? I'm afraid I don't get the point.

Comment: Here i want to use wild card search on a number(its a Long value in entity class and Integer in database).Here the number is Contact_.id(A long value) and searchCriteria.getContactId() will return the number with wild card which is a string.Here it will allow only String expression.So far I have tried with ((Expression<String>)(root.get(Contact_.id).as(String.class).But i am getting query syntex exception.It is not able to convert it to perfect syntex.It is giving query like -> ( cast(generatedAlias0.id as varchar(255)) but not as ( cast(generatedAlias0.id as string)).

Comment: Please let me know if my exception is not clear to you.Thank you in advance.

Comment: The exception is clear to me. Fortunately there are other ways to deal with the problem - see my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i did search with similar tags ,I found a good solution to above problem which uses the criteriabuilder only.I have tried it and Its working fine.
We can find it in below link.

[JPA: How to perform a LIKE with a NUMBER column in a static JPA MetaModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802224/jpa-how-to-perform-a-like-with-a-number-column-in-a-static-jpa-metamodel/19516794#19516794)

Answer (score 1):

Some CriteriaBuilder's methods specified by JPA (like, notLike, concat, substring, trim, lower, upper, length, locate) can only work with strings thus rejecting the integer expression:

```
predicates.add(
    Expression<Long> idExpr = root.get(Contact_.id);
    builder.like(idExpr), // error: Expression<String> is expected
    builder.literal(searchCriteria.getContactId() + "%")
);
```

To workaround the problem you may try to use Hibernate extensions, for example:

- HCQ (Hibernate Criteria Query) with a little help of a native SQL

```java
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contact.class);
c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" CAST(id AS varchar(255)) LIKE '1%'"));
List<Contact> entities = c.list();
```

- HQL (Hibernate Query Language)

```java
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Contact c WHERE STR(c.id) LIKE '1%'");
List<Contact> c= q.list();
```

- SQL

```java
SQLQuery q2 = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Contact " +
                                     "WHERE CAST(id AS varchar(255)) LIKE '1%'");
List<Contact> entities = q.getResultList();
```

---

Looks like only HQL has `STR()` expression or I cannot find equivalent in HCQ. Anyway `STR(c.id)` used in HQL will be translated to `CAST(id AS VARCHAR(255))` clause.

Comment: It will work HCQ,HQL,SQl as you said.Thank you very much.Meanwhile i found in stackoverflow after searching with same topic that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802224/jpa-how-to-perform-a-like-with-a-number-column-in-a-static-jpa-metamodel).Here a new class has been created that will work fine using criteria builder.