# What was Hibernate's CriteriaQueryCompiler replaced with?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Basically I want to use the code this answer gives https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516794 for my project, but compiler is giving me errors. Documentation mentions that CriteriaQueryCompiler is a temporary implementation.

> NOTE : This is a temporary implementation which simply translates the criteria query into a JPAQL query string.
>    A better, long-term solution is being implemented as part of refactoring the JPAQL/HQL translator.

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.9. Is there an analogous implementation of CriteriaQueryCompiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this import,

import org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.RenderingContext;

and then change CriteriaQueryCompiler.RenderingContext to -> RenderingContext in the function parameters.